# A meaning of the abbreviation 'smg'

Tags: lexicography

Sarah Michelle Gellar shares latest 'SMG Tip Of The Day' about hilarious drinking game parents can play while quarantined.

What does "smg" means here?

Comment: It's her initials.

Comment: @nnnnnn ...shouldn't you try to make this into an answer? 104 minutes, and the question hasn't been deleted out of the embarassment, so it's probably here to stay.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thank you very much! I should have guessed!